# Java - Treat an escaping character as a non escaping character

Tags: java, csv

I have a csv file and I'd like to precise which characters are escaping characters and which characteres aren't

My CSV file looks like this :

> "Name";"Firstname";"Number"
>
> "Johnson";"Wa;ter";"035"
>
> "Mitchell";"James";"036"

I don't want the ; of W;lter to be treated as an escaping character and I don't to remove it either (I would prefer not to), so is it possible in Java to treat the ; like a normal character because it's outside the 2 "" ?

Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: Seems like the `;` is irrelevant. Maybe you should be looking for strings inside quotes.

Comment: How are you parsing this CSV? Are you using a CSV parser? Or did you write your own parser? Could you [edit] your question to show the relevant source code from your program?

Comment: Don't write your own CSV generator and parser.

Comment: CSV=Comma Separated Values.  Not Semicolon Separated Values.  As others have said, its a waste of time to write your own CSV parser.  Its already done and there are quite a few edge cases to take care of.

Comment: I have done it with a tfileoutputdelimited component with Talend , but I wanted to fix some problems by adding some java code in a tjava component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your csv was saved using `;` as the separator, notice how `"Name";"Firstname";"Number"` has `;`s separating the cells.

In csv format https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2, the fields may or may not be enclosed in quotes: `"Walter"` and `Walter` are good. If the fields are enclosed in quotes: `"Walter"` to escape a quote that is part of the field you use double quotes: `"W""lter" => W"lter`. If a field contains the delimiter it must be enclosed in quotes: `"W;lter"`.

Your loader might have a bug/misinterpret this so that the separator has to be escaped as well, try `"W;;lter"` or `"W";lter"`. Otherwise save the file with a different separator, like comma.

If the loader has a bug then it is not a good loader, try something from here: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it tomorrow :)